# this as implicit parameter - could not find implicit value for parameter

Tags: scala, implicit, scalatest

I've been trying to pass `WebBrowser` as implicit parameter in a Selenium ScalaTest Spec, but it fails. I have a base superclass for all the tests:

```
abstract class BaseSpec extends FunSpec with WebBrowser with ShouldMatchers {
  implicit val webDriver: WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver
}
```

Then I have a Page Object having a method with implict `WebBrowser` parameter:

```
object LoginPage extends Page {
  def login(username: String, password: String) (implicit browser : WebBrowser ) = {      
    //...
  }
```

And then I want to call the `login` method from the actual spec. As the spec class implements the `WebBrowser` trait via its `BaseSpec` superclass I expect the spec instance calling the method to be resolved as the implicit WebBrowser:

```
class LoginSpec extends BaseSpec {

  it("Should fail on invalid password") {
    LoginPage login("wrong username", "wrong password")
    assertIsOnLoginPage()
  }
}
```

But this fails with compilation error:

> could not find implicit value for parameter browser: org.scalatest.selenium.WebBrowser

on line `LoginPage login("wrong username", "wrong password")`

Do I always need to explicitly provide `this` as the `WebBrowser` parameter value or is there a better way?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4269572/is-it-possible-to-pass-this-as-implicit-parameter-in-scala

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As the spec class implements the WebBrowser trait via its BaseSpec superclass I expect the spec instance calling the method to be resolved as the implicit WebBrowser

`this` isn't available as an implicit automatically, but you can easily add it:

```
abstract class BaseSpec extends FunSpec with WebBrowser with ShouldMatchers {
  implicit def webBrowser: WebBrowser = this
  implicit val webDriver: WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create an implicit val inside `class LoginSpec` as in this code:

```
trait WebBrowser
class WebDriver
class FunSpec
trait ShouldMatchers
class FirefoxDriver extends WebDriver

abstract class BaseSpec extends FunSpec with WebBrowser with ShouldMatchers {
  implicit val webDriver: WebDriver = new FirefoxDriver
}

trait Page

object LoginPage extends Page {
  def login(username: String, password: String)(implicit browser: WebBrowser) = {
    println(username, password)
  }
}

class LoginSpec extends BaseSpec {
  implicit val browser: WebBrowser = this
  def fun = {
    LoginPage login("wrong username", "wrong password")
  }
}

object ImplicitThis {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    new LoginSpec().fun
  }
}
```

This compiles, and works just fine.